# Grunt usemin getting no targets found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin, gruntfile

I followed the following tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIbfDxF69c8

and keep getting No "usemin" targets found.

gruntfile.js:
http://www.billiving.com/demo/script/gruntfile.js

source files:
/script/app/index.html
/script/app/js/file2.js

The process fails and the resulting index.html doesn't contain a link to the minified js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in usemin path.. I was able to figure it out when working in verbose mode. Here's my final output:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

    useminPrepare:{
          html: 'index.html',
          options:{
              dest:'build'
            }
    },

    usemin: {
      html: 'build/index.html'
     },



    copy :{

        task1: {expand: true, src: ['Partials/**', 'Nav/**', 'Resources/Images/**', 'Resources/packages/**', 'Resources/invoices/**', 
        'config.js', 'index.html', 'favicon.ico'], dest:'build/'},
    }       

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');


grunt.registerTask('default',[
  'copy:task1',
  'useminPrepare',
  'concat',
  'uglify',
  'cssmin',
  'usemin'
]);



};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo, it's `usemin:` instead of `usermin:`.